# Heroku - Page will not display because of a PG error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just deployed to Heroku and my build succeeded but the page wont display because of something with PG I believe. Here is my error

```
    2016-04-24T00:15:11.392876+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET   "/users/sign_in" for 98.250.10.59 at 2016-04-24 00:15:11 +0000
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.394581+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.398123+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400469+00:00 app[web.1]: 
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400476+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400477+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE   a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400478+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400479+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400479+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400480+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400481+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400481+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
  2016-04-24T00:15:11.400482+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 2016-04-24T00:15:11.400482+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY        a.attnum
 2016-04-24T00:15:11.400483+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-04-24T00:15:11.400485+00:00 app[web.1]:     vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-  4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in   `async_exec'
```

I'm totally lost at what to do, I've tried to reset the db and all this stuff any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem! All I had to do was run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Check out this, and you won't forget to run migration on heroku later on http://gunpowderlabs.com/blog/automatically-run-migrations-when-deploying-to-heroku/